# Hide WooCommerce specific sub-category in single product pages list output

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

On WooCommerce single product pages, under the add to cart button displays the product category list.

[**In my website**](https://bbgsv2.staging.wpengine.com/goalrilla/in-ground-hoops-goalrilla/gs54-goal/) I have 2 product categories named "In Ground Hoops", so it is getting displayed twice because it is a main category and a sub-category.

How can I hide this sub-category from being displayed there?

I can't target it with CSS and the `woocommerce_template_single_meta` hook is all or nothing from what I can find.

Any ideas on where to start and/or how to do it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your product category and sub-category "In Ground Hoops" has the same term name but different term slugs for each:

- Product category "In Ground Hoops" term slug is: `'in-ground-hoops'`
- Product sub-category "In Ground Hoops" term slug is: `'in-ground-hoops-goalrilla'`

So the only way to distinguish both of them in the code is by their **term ID** or by their **term slug**. So I will use here the **term Slug**…

When looking at **[the responsible template](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/3.2/templates/single-product/meta.php) that is displaying the meta output**, the only way to filter that specific product subcategory is using the available WP `get_the_terms` filter hook:

```
add_filter( 'get_the_terms', 'hide_specific_product_subcategory', 20, 3 );
function hide_specific_product_subcategory( $terms, $post_id, $taxonomy )
{
    // Only on single product pages and for product category custom taxonomy
    if( ! is_product() && $taxonomy != 'product_cat' ) return $terms; // We Exit

    $category = 'in-ground-hoops'; // your main product category
    $subcategory = 'in-ground-hoops-goalrilla'; // the related subcategory
    $taxonomy = 'product_cat'; // product category taxonomy

    if( has_term( $category, $taxonomy, $post_id ) ){
        foreach ($terms as $key => $term){
            if( $term->slug == $subcategory ){
                unset( $terms[$key] );
            }
        }
    }
    return $terms;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).*

Tested and works.